# taskkill fails for process when run from Notepad++ plugin NppExec

Tags: windows-10, batch, notepad++, tasks, nppexec

I made a batch file that kills a couple tasks and restarts them like so:

```
taskkill /f /im "task1.exe"
taskkill /f /im task2.exe
start C:\path\task.exe
```

This bat file runs fine when run through a cmd prompt.  However, when trying to run it through NppExec, the first `taskkill` fails with `Reason: Access is denied.`  The second `taskkill` and the `start` work fine.

Why might one fail and another succeed when running the batch via command prompt has both succeed?  How might I fix it so both tasks end?

Comment: Have you tried running Notepad++ as an administrator?  Taskkill can be fickle with some running apps based on who launched them.  Admin mode can sometimes overcome this, though I'm not sure how the NppExec plugin actually launches things.

Comment: @techturtle That was it, thank you.  I have an admin command line pinned to the taskbar so I forgot I was in an admin console.  If you'd like to make an answer out of that comment, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running Notepad++ as an administrator.  If you use multiple users on the system, you may also want to check which user is running the app.  Taskkill can be fickle with some running apps based on who launched them. Admin mode can sometimes overcome this, though I'm not sure how the NppExec plugin actually launches things.